# Is it possible to use LowerCase or UpperCase with Select *

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, select, sqlite

I'm doing a basic query where I'm doing

```
Select Lower(column-name) from table
```

Now if I want to do a lower case on more than one column, I would need to do a

```
Select Lower(col1), Lower(col2) from table
```

I wanted to know if it's possible to do lowercase function application on all columns.

Something like

```
Select Lower(*) from table
```

This is not a valid statement, when I'm trying on sqlite3 and I'm guessing it's same for other vendors too. Has anybody been able to do this via a different approach. PL/SQL or T-SQL maybe.

Answer (score 7):

No. It isnt possible to fetch all columns in lower case all at once.

Answer (score 2):

I concur that there is no way to do this without mentioning each column. But since your consuming application will presumably have to loop through all columns and rows anyway, I suggest that is the right place to transform this data anyway...

Answer (score 0):

While its not possible to use an inbuilt sql construct to achieve this, yet a small sql script should solve the purpose. Please consider the script given below:

```
declare @number_of_columns int
declare @counter int
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @column_name nvarchar(max)
set @query = 'select '
set @counter = 1
select @number_of_columns = count(ordinal_position) from information_schema.columns where table_name = '<your table name>'
while(@counter <= @number_of_columns) 
begin
select @column_name = column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name = '<your table name>' and ordinal_position = @counter
if(@counter < @number_of_columns)
    begin
        Set @query = @query + 'lower(' + (@column_name) + '),'
    end
else
    begin
        Set @query = @query + 'lower(' + (@column_name) + ')'
    end 
set @counter = @counter + 1
end
set @query = @query + ' from <your table name>'
select @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query = @query
```

While, the above script would not work for 'ntext' data type implicitly as its explicit conversion to varchar is required to apply 'lower' function, also the script might not be required for data types like 'int','datetime' etc. So modify the script by applying additional conditions on the data types of the columns.